# Ranking water basins by canopy cover?

Tags: raster, shapefile, land-cover

I have a river raster that is composed of a range of canopy cover percentages by pixel. I want to rank which water basin's have the river with the best canopy cover. How do I do this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: But how are your water basins defined? If these are defined as polygons you can extract for each basin the raster pixels inside the polygon. (take care how to deal with the boundary and how to deal with the pixels at the borders of the polygon.

Then you can use raster statistics and compute e.g. average canopy cover? In which GIS are you currently working? From: @MarcM

Comment: ArcGIS 10.5.1. I have the watersheds in polygon and raster, and the rivers+canopy cover intersected as both a raster and polygon as well